# How should I make the html elements appear next to each while using ng-bind-html?

Tags: html, css, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a requirement when I should display HTML elements next to each other,
I am using angularjs, when I use ng-bind-html in a HTML tag the next element to it is always appearing in a new line. I want to make the elements appear next to each other.
Could anyone help me in fixing the issue? I've created a sample plunk https://plnkr.co/edit/Bq3x4hw5L1MNkLoJW8LQ?p=preview

I am expecting the result to be

```
I am an HTMLstring with links! and other stuff Sai
```

But its always producing

```
I am an HTMLstring with links! and other stuff

Sai
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a CSS issue, just modify the code as below

```
<div style="display:flex;">
  <p ng-bind-html="myHTML" style="margin: 0;"></p> <span>Sai</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

P element is basically a block element and span an inline element, so when you place span outside p, it will always start on a new line. Just bind your html to an inline element, both will come in same line.

```
<p><span ng-bind-html="myHTML"></span> <span> Sai</span></p>
```